# How to approach instantiating a class within a class in unit testing using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

Having issues on how to approach this test suite. I am asked to instantiate the Beer class within a method in the Bartender class. I want my takeOrder method to take in multiple inputs so therefore I need to call the Beer class constructor inside takeOrder.

This is my Beer class:

```
  constructor(newBeer) {
    this.brewer = newBeer.brewer;
    this.name = newBeer.name;
    this.type = newBeer.type;
    this.price = newBeer.price;
    this.volume = newBeer.volume;
    this.isFlat = false;
  }
}
```

I have to push an instance of Beer into the orders array in the Bartender class and I am not sure how to approach. Here's my code for the Bartender class:

```
class Bartender {
  constructor(name, hourlyWage){
    this.name = name;
    this.hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
    this.orders = [];
  }
  takeOrder(newOrder) {
    var newOrder = new Beer();
    this.orders.push(newOrder);
  }
}
```

I keep getting this error message on my npm test:

```
 1) Bartender
       should be able to take orders:
     AssertionError: expected 'Grand Teton Brewing' to be an instance of Beer
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/bartender-test.js:33:12)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:464:21)
```

This is the bartender unit test I keep failing:

```
it('should be able to take orders', function() {
    var bartender = new Bartender("Chaz", 8.50);

    bartender.takeOrder("Grand Teton Brewing", "Bitch Creek", "Brown Ale", 7, 16);

    assert.instanceOf(bartender.orders[0], Beer);
    assert.equal(bartender.orders.length, 1);
    assert.equal(bartender.orders[0].brewer, 'Grand Teton Brewing');
    assert.equal(bartender.orders[0].name, 'Bitch Creek');
    assert.equal(bartender.orders[0].type, 'Brown Ale');
    assert.equal(bartender.orders[0].price, 7);
    assert.equal(bartender.orders[0].volume, 16);
  });
```

Lmk if anyone has any advice. Thanks.

Comment: Your `Beer` constructor expects a parameter, but you're not passing any in `new Beer()`. And your unit test passes 5 values to `takeOrder`, but your implementation declares only one parameter (but doesn't even use it).

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code.

**First**, the `bartender.takeOrder` function has a bug. `newOrder` as an argument was not used, rather, it was re-declared. Suggest fix

```
takeOrder(newOrder) {
  this.order.push(new Beer(newOrder))
```

**Second**, you passed the wrong argument to `bartender.takeOrder`. When you run, only the first argument `"Grand Teton Brewing"` was used, and rest was discarded.

```
bartender.takeOrder("Grand Teton Brewing", "Bitch Creek", "Brown Ale", 7, 16);
```

Suggest fix, wrap them in an object:

```
bartender.takeOrder({
  brewer: 'Grand Teton Brewing',
  name: '',
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you Julian,

Comment: What would I pass through when I push it into the array? Would I pass that entire object w the five arguments?

Comment: You do need to pass the object with all keys present. I omitted the rest of the keys to save some typing. Keep in mind only instances of `Beer` can be pushed into the array, therefore, it is necessary to push instances instantiated by `new Beer(arg)`